# Python docx module ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, python-docx, modulenotfounderror

**I am a windows 7 user with MS-Office 2016 and python 3.6.**
I recently found out that you can write word documents with python.
I looked on  [how to do that](https://www.roytuts.com/a-guide-to-write-word-file-using-python/)
I installed the docx module:

```
pip install docx
```

But whenever i try to import the docx module i get this error:

```
>>> from docx import Document
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Huzefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Py
in <module>
    from exceptions import PendingDeprecationWarn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'
```

I have even tried this but it wont work:

```
pip install exceptions
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement exceptions (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for exceptions
```

I thought that maybe this is happening because docx is a python-2 module but it is not. I found it out [here](https://www.roytuts.com/a-guide-to-write-word-file-using-python/)

so can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using:

```
pip install python-docx
```

It worked for me!

Comment: this did not work for me on jupyter lab

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the name for installation and usage are different:

- To install: `pip install python-docx`
- To use: `from docx import Document`

Install with the correct name (i.e. `python-docx`) and it shall work.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you can try like this -

```
$ pip install --pre python-docx
```

Or you can also try sudo command -

```
$ sudo pip install --pre python-docx
```

After that try -

```
from docx import Document
```

From here you can find [https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/install.html][1]